# angularjs date filter changes the date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have a ng-repeater and in it I have a date column. I use the code below to format date

```
<td nowrap>{{item.update_date | date:'MMM dd, yyyy'}}</td>
```

When angular formats the date it date goes back 1 day, for example:

> JSON Data: update_date: "2014-11-30T00:00:00"
>
> Result: Nov 29, 2014

any thoughts?

Comment: This seems like a timezone issue, Javascript Date objects are always the client timezone.

Comment: I don't think it is, it happens on my local machine (server and client is same machine) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug in AngularJS and got fixed with version 1.5.2. I was using 1.0.2. Upgrading it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in controller before sending update-date to page:

```
$scope.item.update-date = $filter('date')($scope.item.update-date, "dd/MM/yyyy"):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($scope.dateModels.expDate) {
     invInputView.inputExpiaryDate = 
         $filter('date')($scope.dateModels.expDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
}
```

**I used this code, but it is changing the date to previous date.**